# can a single armature control multiple non-concentric meshes?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

My issue is like this: I have 2 simple ropes that are parallel to each other with an offset. I would like a single armature to control the ropes shapes such that the shapes are identical.
I have tried the intuitive approach of duplicating the The first rope (with the armature within it) and offsetting its position. the first rope animates as expected. the second rope bends properly with the first, but has some undesired wonkiness (see pics).

Is it possible for the second rope to behave exactly as the first with only using the one armature?

Thank you in advance, any help is appreciated!

[image: notice how the bend in the upper rope is different from the lower rope]

Comment: you could correct the weight in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: If u provide blend file, I will take a look

Comment: Hi, and welcome! Do you _mean_ identical, or do you mean offset? (Which is what a clean corner in the top rope would be)

Comment: @moonboots I will look into it. thanks, keywords go a long way!

Comment: @RobinBetts i do want a clean corner, but to define it well, i want rope_2 to be indistiguishable from rope_1 aside from its offset. so i want the corner to be clean because rope_1's corner is clean.

Comment: @Chris Wow thank you so much! took me a minute to figure how to share a file and then clear the space. This isnt the exact file i was working in, but a clean minimalistic version of the issue. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AnCi2j3SPCTaRqqzqOUvTS7QGh8aLEr2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @TBaby: thank you for providing a blend file! i tried it...but unfortunately i couldn't make it. And i am not sure whether Blender can handle this, but hopefully some rigging experts know how to do it. I also tried other solution like mesh deform modifier...but couldn't solve that too.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for trying! I really wouldn't/didn't expect someone to check out a project file.